# C# Regex.Replace not matching and removing double quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I googled for an answer and I found some questions here on Stack Exchange asking similar question but they didn't help me. For example, I found [C# regex - not matching my string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619520/c-sharp-regex-not-matching-my-string) but the answers given are way too complicated for me to understand. I don't know or understand regex. All I want to do is strip a double quote from a string.

To put my question simply, I have a string "\"123.456\"" and I need to remove the "\""

so I made my expression "[^\w\\"]" and after calling

```
string myString Regex.Replace("\"123.456\"", "[^\\w\\\"]", "",
                    RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
```

myString is "\"123.456\"". I just need to know what my expression should be. I won't be able to understand any lengthy discussions or lectures on learning regex.

I got my example directly from Microsoft at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/844skk0h(v=vs.110).aspx so basically all I did was replace the ".@-" with "\"".

UPDATE
Apparently trying to ask a simple question only attracts trolls. I didn't want to get too complicated because I didn't want all you hard working busy people to spend too much time answering the wrong question. I was trying to be nice.

We have a situation where we need to parse input files from several clients and going forwards, the number of clients will increase and there also the number of files from each client will increase.

We found that in several of our clients' transmitted files many fields will have various extra characters. We don't know how or why those characters are in there and our clients aren't telling. (if you want to know why they aren't telling, please move along, these aren't the questions you are looking for)

So, we have many files from many clients each with many rows with many fields of data and we need to strip out "bad" characters.

I took Microsofts method and changed it a bit to be more dynamic.

```
    private string CleanInput(string strIn, string chars)
    {
        // Replace invalid characters with empty strings. 
        try
        {
            string regexString = string.Format(@"[^\w\{0}]", chars);
            return Regex.Replace(strIn, regexString, "",
                                 RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
        }
        // If we timeout when replacing invalid characters,  
        // we should return Empty. 
        catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
```

goal here is to be able to strip out any characters that don't belong dynamically But we can't just hard code those characters because not all fields will have any of these characters, and more importantly, some fields will have some bad characters along with other characters which are not to be considered bad for that field but may be considered bad for other fields.

With me so far?

So, in trying to get my work done by Friday (yes, tomorrow), I decided to start slowly with only a couple of known bad characters from 3 input files. So far, those characters are single quote, dash, double quote, dollar sign, comma. But not all the fields in my 3 files need these characters stripped, so I intend to call the CleanInput method only on those fields that need it, and only for the characters that we need stripped.

OK, so while I was testing, I discovered on one field, where we want to strip the comma, single quote, double quote and dollar sign, it was not removing the double quotes (an apparently the backslashes too). So I debugged this issue by first passing in only the comma -that worked. Then I tried passing in only the single quote - that worked. Then I passed in the dollar sign - that worked. Then I passed in the escaped double quote -and that didn't work - the double quotes are still in the string. So I simplified my test in a new console project and I hard coded the string and I called my method just to make sure nothing else could be interfering with it.

I hope and pray no one spends hours of their precious time trying to reconfigure my input files or attempting to teach me the end all be all of regex programming. I have to get this done by tomorrow. Please, I only want to know how to strip the double quote (and apparently the backslashes too) from the given string.

Comment: Are you looking to replace both quotes? i.e. you want to end up with `123.456`?

Comment: You realize that `\"` is one character, not two, right?

Comment: If you just want to remove leading and trailing `"` characters, you can use `yourString = yourString.Trim('"')`.

Comment: What is the final string you want to receive?

Comment: `.Replace("\"","")` doesn't work?

Comment: These are all great questions, but I have to use regex because in the future we will have to strip more characters out of strings. The strings are being read in from a tab delimited file transmitted from our clients, so who knows what we'll find in them going forward. For now, I need to use regex to turn "\"123.456\"" into "123.456"

Comment: @James And you want a generic answer for unknown specifications ?

Comment: @L.B. No, for right now I need a regex expression that will strip the double quotes from the string "\"123.456\""

Answer (score 2):

Rather than getting regex involved, perhaps you can just use Replace?

```
var myString = "\\\"123.456\\\"";
var myCleanString = myString.Replace(@"\""", "");
```

Comment: Yes.  KISS.  Regex is a complicated solution to a simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are matching on a negated group (the `[^]` bit). This matches any character *not* in the square brackets and replaces it. You want to replace anything that *is* in the group which you can do by just placing the characters you wish to replace inside the square brackets and remove the negation (`^`):

```
private static string CleanInput(string strIn, string chars)
{
    // Replace invalid characters with empty strings. 
    try
    {
        string regexString = string.Format(@"[{0}]", chars);
        return Regex.Replace(strIn, regexString, "",
                                RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
    }
    // If we timeout when replacing invalid characters,  
    // we should return Empty. 
    catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

You would use the negative version if you knew what you wanted to include rather than exclude. For example if you knew you only wanted numbers and the period character you could do:

```
string myString = Regex.Replace("\"123.456\"", "[^\\d.]", "",
                RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
```